# Tomcat is looking for javax.servlet.Filter but I have jakarta.servlet.Filter

Tags: java, tomcat, struts

I created a dynamic web project on Struts and when I tried to execute it, I get the error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter

> The problem is Tomcat is looking for `javax.servlet.Filter` but >I have `jakarta.servlet.Filter`

```
Tomcat Version : 10.0
Struts Version : 2.5
```

Could anyone please help?

[image: Jakarta Library Image]

Project Tree

[image]

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC 
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN" 
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">  
<struts>
    <package name="first" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="Action" class="guild.Action">  
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>   
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>  
        </action>
    </package>  
</struts>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="5.0">
  <display-name>FSGuild</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Action.java

```
package guild;

public class Action {
    public String execute() {
        System.out.println("Someone called execute");
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

error.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ERROR</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

success.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>SUCCESS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>SUCCESS</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If Tomcat is searching for `javax.servlet.Filter`, that would suggest you're using Tomcat 9 or earlier.

Comment: Alternatively, the struts library you're using doesn't support the jakarta.* namespace, and instead provides classes requiring the classes from `javax.servlet.*`, which then fails when they are loaded. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I am developing my first project on struts only so no issues there, I will update in question itself

Comment: As far as I can tell, Struts doesn't provide a version supporting Jakarta EE 9 or higher (it still [requires Servlet spec 3.1](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/pom.xml#L788), which uses the javax.servlet packages). You'll need to use Tomcat 9 or lower, or consider using something other than Struts. See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-5141

Comment: > Tomcat version 9.0 only supports J2EE 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, and Java EE 5, 6, 7, and 8 Web modules
This is what eclipse says and its not allowing me to run the application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250488/discussion-between-anubhav-sharma-and-mark-rotteveel).

Comment: That's because you've defined your application as a Servlet spec 5.0 application. However, Struts doesn't work under Servlet spec 5.0 or higher because of the change in package names.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I suggest you make an Answer of your Comments so we can resolve this Question, and be able to refer to it in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using Struts, and Struts has not been updated to support Servlet specification 5.0 or higher (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-5141). Servlet specification 5.0 introduced the big breaking change of moving the API from the package `javax.servlet` to `jakarta.servlet`. This means that libraries, etc., still using the old package names cannot be used.

You need to switch to Tomcat 9 and define your application as a Servlet specification 4.0 web application (or Servlet specification 3.1).